# Query to get list of all roles and their associated users in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to get list of all users along with the roles that are assigned to those users in a single query in snowflake.

```
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE1; --> This gives me list of all users assigned to ROLE1
```

BUT I Cannot do something like below -

```
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE1
UNION ALL
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE2
UNION ALL
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE3;
```

Objective is to achieve something like above in a single query of snowflake.

Regards,
Yogesh

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog post [here](https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/02/21/getting-a-complete-list-of-user-privileges-in-snowflake/) that explains how to get the role hierarchy (list of roles in which each user is a member) and effective privileges (a complete list of privileges per user for all grant types). I think the first query may be closer to what you want, but I'm including both:

```
-- The data returned by both queries is in the
-- SNOWFLAKE database, which has latency of up
-- to 3 hours to reflect changes

-- Get the effective role hierarchy for each user.
with
   -- CTE gets all the roles each role is granted
   ROLE_MEMBERSHIPS(ROLE_GRANTEE, ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE)
   as
    (
    select   GRANTEE_NAME, "NAME"
    from     SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
    where    GRANTED_TO = 'ROLE' and
             GRANTED_ON = 'ROLE' and
             DELETED_ON is null
    ),
    -- CTE gets all roles a user is granted
    USER_MEMBERSHIPS(ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER, USER_GRANTEE, GRANTED_BY)
    as
     (
     select ROLE,
            GRANTEE_NAME,
            GRANTED_BY
     from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
     where DELETED_ON is null
     )
-- 
select
        USER_GRANTEE,
        case
            when ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE is null
                then ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER 
            else ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
        end
        EFFECTIVE_ROLE,
        GRANTED_BY,
        ROLE_GRANTEE,
        ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER,
        ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
from    USER_MEMBERSHIPS U
    left join ROLE_MEMBERSHIPS R
        on U.ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER = R.ROLE_GRANTEE
;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- This gets all the grants for all of the users:
with
    ROLE_MEMBERSHIPS
        (
            ROLE_GRANTEE, 
            ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
        )
    as
    (
        -- This lists all the roles a role is in
        select   GRANTEE_NAME, "NAME"
        from     SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
        where    GRANTED_TO = 'ROLE' and
                 GRANTED_ON = 'ROLE' and
                 DELETED_ON is null
    ),
    USER_MEMBERSHIPS
        (
            ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER,
            USER_GRANTEE,
            GRANTED_BY
        )
    as
     (
        select ROLE,GRANTEE_NAME,GRANTED_BY
        from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
        where DELETED_ON is null
     ),
    EFFECTIVE_ROLES
    (
        USER_GRANTEE,
        EFFECTIVE_ROLE,
        GRANTED_BY,
        ROLE_GRANTEE,
        ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER,
        ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
    )
    as
    (
        select
            USER_GRANTEE,
            case
                when ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE is null
                    then ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER
                else ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
            end
            EFFECTIVE_ROLE,
            GRANTED_BY,
            ROLE_GRANTEE,
            ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER,
            ROLE_GRANTED_THROUGH_ROLE
        from USER_MEMBERSHIPS U
            left join ROLE_MEMBERSHIPS R
            on U.ROLE_GRANTED_TO_USER = R.ROLE_GRANTEE
    ),
    GRANT_LIST
        (
            CREATED_ON,
            MODIFIED_ON,
            PRIVILEGE,
            GRANTED_ON, 
            "NAME",
            TABLE_CATALOG,
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            GRANTED_TO,
            GRANTEE_NAME,
            GRANT_OPTION
        )
    as
    (
        -- This shows all the grants (other than to roles)
        select  CREATED_ON,
                MODIFIED_ON,
                PRIVILEGE,
                "NAME",
                TABLE_CATALOG,
                TABLE_SCHEMA,
                GRANTED_TO,
                GRANTEE_NAME,
                GRANT_OPTION,
                GRANTED_ON
        from    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
        where   GRANTED_ON <> 'ROLE' and
                PRIVILEGE <> 'USAGE' and
                DELETED_ON is null
    )
select * from EFFECTIVE_ROLES R
    left join GRANT_LIST G 
        on G.GRANTED_TO = R.EFFECTIVE_ROLE
where G.PRIVILEGE is not null
;
```

Comment: I also need to get role access to each DB to identify if it is read or write access. Any help on this

Comment: I think your query will select users whose role has been revoked, because a past grant will still select `DELETED_ON is null`

Answer (score 1):

A number of queries in snowflake are not *really* queries, so you have to fetch the results in an extra step using `result_scan(-N)` to fetch them

```
show grants to ROLE accountadmin;

show grants to ROLE sysadmin;

select * from table(result_scan(-1))
union all
select * from table(result_scan(-2));
```

works for me as you want...

Answer (score 0):

More easy solution:

```
 SELECT  ROLE_NAME FROM SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.APPLICABLE_ROLES
     START WITH GRANTEE in(select distinct ROLE from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS GTU 
    join  SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS u on u.name = GTU.grantee_name
        where GTU.DELETED_ON is NULL AND not U.DISABLED AND not
 U.SNOWFLAKE_LOCK and U.DELETED_ON is null and U.LOGIN_NAME ='USER' ) 
    CONNECT BY GRANTEE = PRIOR ROLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `snowflake.account_usage`, this query solves your problem:

```sql
with granted as (
    select * from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_users
    where role in ('ROLE1', 'ROLE2', 'ROLE3')
    qualify row_number() over (partition by role, grantee_name order by created_on desc) = 1
)
select distinct grantee_name as name, role from granted where deleted_on is null
order by name;
```

Note: I think other answers that rely on `grants_to_users` are incorrect in that they include revoked roles, because they don't have a condition on pairs (role, grantee) being *the most recent* with `deleted_on is null`.