# How to get User-Role Hierarchy in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some help to get display of User-Role hierarchy. As per audit requirement I need to create role hierarchy dashboard. I didn't find any direct way to get this as role inheritance and nested roles. This goes in Many-Many relation. One user can have one or more roles assiged to it and one role may have one or more roles assiged to it. I am trying to get this information from below views

```
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
```

Here is some information.
User DBA has environment level roles (Role_DEV as of today but it will have another Role_STG very soon), which has corresponding READ and WRITE Roles. These are based on Schema level.

Here is the hierarchy and I need to get display like this or similar

```
User_DBA ==> Role_DBA ==> Role_DEV ==> Role_Write ==> Role_Read ==> Role_Read_Schema_A
User_DBA ==> Role_DBA ==> Role_DEV ==> Role_Write ==> Role_Read ==> Role_Read_Schema_B
User_DBA ==> Role_DBA ==> Role_DEV ==> Role_Write ==> Role_Write_Schema_A
User_DBA ==> Role_DBA ==> Role_DEV ==> Role_Write ==> Role_Write_Schema_B
```

ETL User Role Hierarchy

```
User_ETL ==> Role_ETL ==> Role_ETL_DEV ==> Role_WRITE_Schema_A ==> Role_Read_Schema_A
User_ETL ==> Role_ETL ==> Role_ETL_DEV ==> Role_Read_Schema_B
```

Reporting Role Hierarchy (No default role to reporting user)

```
User_Rpt ==> Role_Read_Schema_A
User_Rpt ==> Role_Read_Schema_B
```

Any suggestion or approach?

Thank you,
Shrini

Comment: The views should have the information you are looking for.  What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: This previous answer will probably get you most of the way there:
[Query to get list of all roles and their associated users in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923894/query-to-get-list-of-all-roles-and-their-associated-users-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of getting the role hierarchy that you are looking for. I think you could use this example and add in the `grants_to_users` view to get what you are looking for.

```sql
    with initial_table as (
      select
        name as node,
        grantee_name as parent
      from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles
      where deleted_on is null and granted_on = 'ROLE'
      union all
      select 'ACCOUNTADMIN' as node, '' as parent
    )
    select
      node,
      parent,
      sys_connect_by_path(node, ' ==> ') as path
    from initial_table
      start with node = 'ACCOUNTADMIN'
      connect by parent = prior node
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely this helps for me to further work on it. Using this I will try to find out down level hierarchy. 
E.x. If User has assigned to ONLY one role as WRITE_ROLE then I need to shows inheritence of WRITE_ROLE

USER_1 ==> WRITE_ROLE ==> READ_ROLE

In this case I don't need to show Upper level hierarcy, which is ACCOUNTADMIN, SYSADMIN.